# Image view not updating after fetching image from URL

Tags: ios

I'm using `AFNetworking` category `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` in order to download an image from S3. I get a pre-signed URLRequest and proceed to get the image. This is in a controller solely meant to display a photo:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [BFAWSUploader downloadPhotoWithFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", _topicMessage.attachment_s3_name]];
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [_imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        NSLog(@"Pulled down image successfully");
        [hud hide:YES];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to pull down image");
    }];
}
```

I see the log entry "Pulled down image successfully", but I'm not seeing the image view update after that. Instead, I have to leave the view controller and then go back in, and I'll see the cached entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`:

"If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block to set the image of the image view before returning. If no success block is specified, the default behavior of setting the image with `self.image = image` is executed."

So, you need `_imageView.image = image` inside your success block.